# How can I allow footer to have their own margin?

Tags: header-footer, margins

I'm required to have a strange margin of `left=3.14in`. What would be a good way for the footers to ignore this and instead adhere to left and right margins of `.75in`? MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} % investigate tbu
\usepackage{geometry} % package link.  tbu explanation.
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % allows table row highlighting
\usepackage{tabularx} % package link.  tbu explanation.
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} % package link.  tbu explanation.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % package link. tbu explanation.
\usepackage{enumitem}% package link. for lists.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xhfill} % tbu
\geometry{top=1.25in, left=3.14in, right=.75in, bottom=.81in}
% subsection format setup
\titleformat{name=\subsection,numberless}[runin]{\bfseries\large\color{black}}{}{0em}{\llap{\smash{\begin{tabularx}{2.25in}[t]{@{}l@{\hskip0.4em}>{\raggedright}X@{\hskip\marginparsep}} & #1\end{tabularx}}}}[\leavevmode\hspace*{\dimexpr-\fontdimen2\font-\fontdimen3\font}] % MM deleted \thesubsection to remove numbering
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % no indent for entire file
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{\small The left footer}
\rfoot{\small The right footer}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you mean "footer" instead of "footnote", you should perhaps edit your question title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Both header and footer are changed

Changing the margin for both the header and footer lines can be done easily with `fancyhdr` since version 3.0 via the new command `\fancyhfoffset`:

```
\fancyhfoffset[l]{\dimexpr3.14in-.75in\relax}
```

Second page:

> [image: Result]

## Changing footer margins only

Moving the footer line to the left can be done with a negative `\kern`:

```
\lfoot{\mbox{\kern\dimexpr-3.14in+.75in\relax\small The left footer}}
\cfoot{\mbox{\kern\dimexpr-3.14in+.75in\relax \thepage}}
\rfoot{\small The right footer}
```

(`\small` for the page number as well?)

> [image: Result]